# IDE for editing Firebase Database Permissions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Does there exist any IDE that supports editing Firebase Database Permissions? The web editor is very basic and makes editing complex permissions challenging. Would be nice to have auto format, remove trailing spaces and auto indent functionalities.

Comment: I don't think such a tool exists.

Answer (score 1):

#### Any editor that can handle JSON

I find Adobe Brackets very good for this. Copy your Firebase rules from the Firebase Rules web editor and paste into Brackets, and save it as a ".json" file in a convenient place for your project development.

Once saved (so that Brackets knows to interpret as JSON), the auto-syntax-coloring will work.

You can then use whatever plugin you like to do the auto-indenting etc, for example Brackets Beautifier and CTRL-ALT-B.

I am guessing you could alternatively use any text editor that can highlight and pretty-print JSON files.

*Update 2023:*

#### VS Code has an extension `me-dutour-mathieu.vscode-firebase`

This has special linting for firebase rules.

[image]